# Save Data from API to database Laravel

Tags: laravel, api

i want to save data from third party API to my database using laravel, how i create the code?

i try, but i get some error and failed

this is my controller code

```
public function store(Request $request, Gallery $gallery)
{
    $gallery = new Gallery(['headers' => ['Accept' => 'application/json']]);
    $res = $gallery->request('POST','https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/MIZONEDanceBattle/?__a=1');
    $data = json_decode($res->getBody()->getContents(), true);
    dd($data);
    $data = Gallery::firtsOrCreate([
            'shortcode',
            'thumbnail_src',
        ]);
    $data->save();
    return ;
}
```

Comment: Have you retrieved data successfully? I mean `dd($data)` return data success fully?

Comment: **i try, but i get some error and failed.** What error you got? Also please share $data output

Comment: @AmitSenjaliya i didn't get anythings, just white blank screen

Comment: @AnangMa'ruf It means your API not working first thing.

Comment: https://quantizd.com/integrating-instagram-api-in-laravel-5-6/ Please Check this Reference link it may help you.

Comment: @AmitSenjaliya no, failed just show white screen

Comment: i want to save data from API to My database

Comment: First change your `POST` request to `GET` to get the result `$res = $gallery->request('GET','https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/MIZONEDanceBattle/?__a=1');`

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your `POST` method to `GET` method to get the data from API
then use the below code.

```
$res = $gallery->request('GET','https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/MIZONEDanceBattle/?__a=1');
    $data = json_decode($res->getBody()->getContents(), true);

    $gallery = Gallery::firtsOrCreate([
            'shortcode',
            'thumbnail_src',
        ], $data]); // add $data here
    $gallery->save();
```

Reference:
[Laravel API -> Builder ->Method firstOrCreate](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_firstOrCreate)